# How to make a recursive CTE query for to convert this table into this other

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQLServer with this hierarchy:

[image: Table with ID_CENTRO(Children) and id_centro_padre(Father)]

And I want to convert that relation into this table with a cte, but I'm really struggling:

[image: Hierarchy table]

I want a query to build the hierarchy in columns, but I can't find a solution.
How I should do this?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried so far so we can help you find the solution yourself

Comment: Easy. I will show you exactly how, when to past the data in normal format, from which I can copy it and use it.

Comment: please [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/57475) and try to format your question in a way that makes it easier to answer as @gotqn suggests